# Why is my second label not updating?

Tags: python

For some reason, I can't update the second label. I tested it by asking for input and print out strings and it worked so I apparently did not write the label update function correctly. Any ideas?

```
import wx
import time


class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.text = parent.GetParent().rightPanel.text
        self.text_2 = parent.GetParent().rightPanel.text_2
        button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Count', (10, 10))
        button2 = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Countdown', (10, 60))
        button3 = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Action', (10, 110))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlus, id=button1.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnMinus, id=button2.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_Pressed, id=button3.GetId())
        self.timed_Out = 1     


    def OnPlus(self, event):
        value = 1
        for t in range(50):
            value = value + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            wx.Yield()
            self.text.SetLabel(str(value))

    def OnMinus(self, event):

        value = 60
        for t in range(value):
            value = value - 1
            time.sleep(1)
            wx.Yield()
            self.text.SetLabel(str(value/60) + ':' + str(value%60))

        self.timed_Out = 0
        self.text_2.SetLabel(str('End o\'line.'))

    def button_Pressed(self, event):
        if self.timed_Out == 1:
            if self.text_2 == 'First':
                self.text_2.SetLabel('Second')

            elif self.text_2 == 'Second':
                 self.text_2.SetLabel('First')


class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '0', (10,60))
        self.text_2 = wx.StaticText(self,-1,'First',(10, 120))

class Communicate(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.rightPanel = RightPanel(panel, -1)
        leftPanel = LeftPanel(panel, -1)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        hbox.Add(leftPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 4)
        hbox.Add(self.rightPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)



app = wx.App()
Communicate(None, -1, 'widgets communicate')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `button_Pressed`, you're testing `self.text_2` for equality with `"First"` or `"Second"`, but `text_2` is a `StaticText` object, not a string, so the test doesn't work. Try this:

```
if self.text_2.GetLabelText() == 'First':
```

Comment: Ok...I only tried the Get() method lastnight (it was the only Get method I knew of). I thought that self.text_2 would be treated like any other variable assigned a value. a=2 if a==2:print(a)           Thank you much sir or ma'am. :)

Comment: @JoryRFerrell that's one of those things where the wx API could have been made more intuitive, but it just wasn't. This is unfortunately typical of python wrappers around C APIs.